# Wrting to an existing csv file with access vba

Tags: vba, csv

I would like to write some data to a csv file. I am using this code:

```
 Dim Filename As String, line As String
    Dim A As Integer
    Filename = "D:" & "\testfile.csv"
    Open Filename For Output As #1
    For A = 1 To 100
    Print #1, "test, test, test"
    Next A
    Close #1
```

but the problem is, that this code rewrite  this cvs file from the beginning. but I would like to add data at the end of csv file ( For example if I run this code three times, I would like to have 300 lines in this csv file)

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which case you need `Open Filename For Append As #1`.

You might also find that `Write #1,` behaves better than `Print #1,` if you line contains quotation characters.

One last thing, don't hardcode the `#1` as someone else may be using that handle. Instead, use

```
Dim n as Integer
n = Freefile 'Let VBA find a free file handle
'use #n rather than #1 from here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Error:

```
Open Filename For Output As #1
```

which should be:

```
Open Filename For Append As #1
```

This will append your new text to the end of a stream.